# Highlighting text when a knockout variable is "true"?

Tags: knockout.js

When a user clicks "edit" for a given element on the page, I'd like to highlight the text of the content being edited so the user doesn't have to click on the input area.

I have the following:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.title = ko.observable("title");
    self.editing = ko.observable(false);
    if (self.editing()) {
       // highlight text in DOM?
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Here's the jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/85/

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the hasfocus binding in your view.  Generally speaking, anything view specific should be kept out of the VM if possible, and should be handled via built in bindings or with custom bindings.

```
<input class="title-input" data-bind="value: title, hasfocus: editing"
```

updated your fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/87/

**Updated**: 
selecting the input text can be done with a custom binding. Someone else has already answered how to do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12297619/2421292

Comment: sweet.  How would I highlight that text?

Answer (score 0):

css binding:-

```
<input class="title-input" data-bind="value: title, css: {HL : editing()}"/>
```

css:

```
.HL {
    background: #ffff99; 
    color: #000000;
    }
```